# In database cell find keyword to pull information out of 'quotes' keeping line breaks to put into seperate <li> tags

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using php to pull information out of a database, but I have come to a stumbling block with this issue:

I have an `extra` column, where the cells contain a few different values laid out like `keyword='lots of data'`. This is an example of a cell's content:

> eTestOne='This would be one sentence.
>   This would be another.'
>   eTestTwo='1 Test
>   1 Other Test
>   2 Other Tests'
>   eTestThree='This would be another entry'

So basically I need to find the keyword `eTestTwo` and pull out the info from the 'quotes' keeping the line breaks to put into separate `<li>` tags.

I have got sort of halfway I think. This is the **php** I have so far:

```
$pos = stripos($info['extra'], "eTestTwo='");
echo substr($info['extra'], $pos + 9 );
```

But this doesn't strip off the extra information after the closing quote mark and doesn't help me distinguish between each line to put into their own `<li>`:

> 1 Test
>   1 Other Test
>   2 Other Tests'
>   eTestThree='This would be another entry'

The final output I am trying to achieve is:

```
<li>1 Test</li>
<li>1 Other Test</li>
<li>2 Other Tests</li>
```

**EDIT :** Just to clarify, the cell can contain more or less values in no particular order. So the solution really needs to rely on finding the keyword `eTestTwo` and somehow grabbing the info from between its quotes.

Comment: Why did you choose this method? What 'eTestXXX' stands for?

Comment: I didn't choose the method. It is a pre-existing database, and I need the information. `eTestXXX` is just a keyword referring to whatever information is contained between the quotes e.g. details, summary, id etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2:

```
    $parts = explode("eTestTwo" , $info['extra']);
    $temp = explode("'" ,$parts[1]);
    /*
     temp[0] = "="
     temp[1] = "1 Test
1 Other Test
2 Other Tests"
     temp[2] = "...."
    */
    $lines = explode("\r" , $temp[1]);
    unset($temp);
    foreach($lines as $line)
      echo "<li>".$line."</li>";
```

Old anwer:

```
    $parts = explode("=" , $info['extra']);
    /*
    parts[0] = eTestOne
    parts[1] = 'This would be one sentence.
    This would be another.'
    parts[2] = eTestTwo
    parts[3] = '1 Test
    1 Other Test
    2 Other Tests'
    ...
    */

    $lines = explode("\n" , $parts[3]);
    foreach($lines as $line)
     echo "<li>".$line."</li>";

//It will work only if there are no '=' chars in the quotes.
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But unfortunately this leads to other problems: I only know the keyword `eTestTwo` and won't know which number in the array it is, as there may be more or less entries in the cell. The other issue is: when the result from the `$lines = explode` and `foreach` is echoed out it doesn't appear to keep the new lines and puts it all into one <li> and the surrounding quote marks are still there. EDIT: replacing `\n` with `\r` solved the new line issue. But not the surrounding quotes or not knowing where it is issue.

Comment: give a try to my new answer (EDITED)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but the problem I have is that I won't know what `eTestThree` is. It is a column where the cells can be filled with all sorts of values with no set order. All I know is the keyword I am searching for `eTestTwo`.

Comment: edited my answer once again , now it doesn't matter if you are having eTestThree or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the delay in accepting your answer. It worked well, though I did have to have a little play around with `\n` and `\r` to get it to work properly and I also modified it a tad so that it wouldn't spit out a blank `$line`.